# long doesn't equal another long in C++

Tags: c++, long-integer

It never goes in the if statment when obviously `0 == 0` the sizeof() of both the function return long and regular long both say 8, I don't know what else could be wrong here.

Declarations:

```
long                        RemoteStep; // Next packet number to-be-processed

long GetLong(BYTE * Message, const SHORT Offset)
{   // Get a long from a char *
    return *(long*)&(Message[Offset]);
}
```

Debug code:

```
printf("id = %d  remotestep = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
printf("id = %d  remotestep = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
printf("id = %d  remotestep = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
printf("equals = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2) == RemoteStep);
printf("sizeof = %d - %d\n", sizeof(GetLong(Packet->Message, 2)), sizeof(RemoteStep));
        // Process if expected
        if (GetLong(Packet->Message, 2) == RemoteStep)
        {
            printf("in.............\n");
            ...
        }
```

Output information:

```
id = 0  remotestep = 0
id = 0  remotestep = 0
id = 0  remotestep = 0
equals = 0
sizeof = 8 - 8
id = 1  remotestep = 0
id = 1  remotestep = 0
id = 1  remotestep = 0
equals = 0
sizeof = 8 - 8
```

I compiled this under `compat-gcc-34-c++` aka `g++34`, I can't use newer g++ compilers as they give too much warnings and even errors.

with `-Wall -Wextra`

```
declares.h:1880: warning: int format, different type arg (arg 2)
declares.h:1880: warning: int format, different type arg (arg 3)
declares.h:1880: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1880: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1880: warning: too many arguments for format
declares.h:1881: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1881: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1881: warning: too many arguments for format
declares.h:1882: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1882: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
declares.h:1882: warning: too many arguments for format
declares.h:1884: warning: int format, different type arg (arg 2)
declares.h:1884: warning: int format, different type arg (arg 3)
```

line 1880 is one of the

```
printf("id = %l  remotestep = %l \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
```

Comment: Turn on the compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: Printing a `long` using `%d` has undefined behavior, although that might not be the reason for the problem.

Comment: `%d` format specifier is for `int`, not `long`. Try with `%l`. I have a hunch that `id` won't show 0 anymore.

Comment: yes with both `%l` shows `id = %  remotestep = %`

Comment: Use `%ld` for `long`, not `%l`.

Comment: `id = 29703315214303232  remotestep = 0` next one is `id = 3388729196545  remotestep = 0` how do I fix that?

Comment: @user3435580: Check how many bytes `GetLong` is supposed to read - my guess is that the message format uses the word "Long" to mean 4 bytes, while your compiler defines `long` to be 8 bytes, and so you read an extra 4 bytes of garbage. To read the message portably, stick to fixed-width types like `uint32_t`.

Comment: Casting `char*` to `long*` and deferencing it will read additional bytes after `Message[Offset]`. Those bytes apparently aren't all 0 and the resulting value won't be either.

Comment: Yes `getLong` is suppose to be 32bit function, strange why it's coded like this

Comment: Also, `return *(long*)&(Message[Offset]);` causes undefined behaviour if it is not correctly aligned , and may also trap

Comment: Can I quickfix this with some `typedef long int;` or something? I think everything will be broken that's a `long`

Comment: No, but you could grep for `%` to find other broken format specifies (if that's what you mean)

Comment: @user3435580: "strange why it's coded like this" -- whoever wrote it was probably using a 32-bit C++ implementation (specifically, one with a 32 bit long, in practice the ones with 32 bit pointers mostly have 32 bit long too). They did not understand the requirements of programming portably. "Works for me, ship it".

Comment: Maybe your compiler would have a switch to control the size of `long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `long` type should not be printed with `%d`, this is explicitly undefined in the specification. For example,

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character ...
>   ...
>   If a conversion specification does not match one of the above forms, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.
>   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html

(the documentation applies to `printf` as well as `fprintf`)

---

Thus you cannot rely on the output of,

```
printf("id = %d  remotestep = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
```

to determine that

```
printf("equals = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2) == RemoteStep);
//output: equals = 0
```

is in fact incorrect, and you will need to fix your debug statements first:

```
printf("id = %ld  remotestep = %ld \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);
```

---

In your case it is also preferable to use `memcpy` instead of the pointer cast,

```
long GetLong(BYTE * Message, const SHORT Offset)
{   
    long result;
    std::memcpy(&result, &(Message[Offset]), sizeof(long)); 
    return result;
}
```

since `long*` can have a stricter alignment requirement on your platform than a `char*`.

Comment: hehe you mean `%ld` :P haha same mistake

Comment: :) yes it's late, fixed, btw I think Mike Seymour is correct (and he needs to make it an answer if you confirm), you need to make sure you do want to read **8** bytes.

Comment: Here is proof `if (GetLong(Packet->Message, 1) != 0xFFFFFFFF)` biggest value I found and it's a 32bit.

Comment: What is that supposed to be proof of?

Comment: Even better than `memcpy` would be code that explicity says what is intended; e.g. `unsigned long result = Message[Offset] + Message[Offset+1] * 0x100ul + Message[Offset+2] * 0x10000ul + ...`. If it'd been done that way the first time, then the `sizeof(long)` issue would have made no difference.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree that it would be more explicit, but marginally slower. Also harder to generalise for different types. But possibly for the OP to get it right and really understand the format of their `Message` your advice is the best initial approach.

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence that it was slower.  And I don't see what you mean by generalizing; we're decoding a serialized format that presumably has a fixed number of bytes that we are meant to be reading.

Comment: @MattMcNabb We will have to remain in the hand-waving domain, nothing to be seen without concrete benchmarks, that said, `memcpy` implementations are typically inlined and optimised for the target architecture, and I am not convinced that multiple read/add/multiply assembly commands will be faster here. By generalising, I was referring to `GetLong` being a particular case of `GetT` with `T=long`.

Comment: Rename it to GetFourBytes then :) We should be dealing in fixed widths here, it seems.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Agree :) and throw in an `int32_t` as the return value for portability.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your statements to use std::cout instead of printf, since you tagged the question with C++ and not with C. With cout you will not get these surprising effects of %d or other % specifiers during runtime.

`printf("id = %d  remotestep = %d \n", GetLong(Packet->Message, 2), RemoteStep);`

can probably be replaced by

`std::cout << "id = " << GetLong( Packet->Message, 2 ) << " remotestep = " << RemoteStep << " \n";`

Comment: While I prefer streams myself, it is simply not true that you should always use them instead of C functions. `printf` et al do have a few advantages over C++ streams: 1.) more readable and more concise for really complex formats, 2.) more likely to be faster, 3.) easier to use for internationalisation and localisation. However, it should also be said that there are libraries like Boost.Format which combine most of the distinct advantages.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Luckily I never stated that 'you should always use them instead of C functions'. ;)
Besides that, I agree with you on #1, I'm skeptical about #2 and I have no experience with #3 or Boost.Format (yet).

Comment: Well, #3 means that a format string can be read completely from outside at run-time, whereas streams tend to result in everything put together at compile-time. Think of a string like "Execute %s", %s referring to the name of some command in the UI, and consider that in German, it would have to be "%s ausführen", i.e. with a different word order.

Comment: Thank you for that example, although I guess one would use Boost.Format if type safety is wanted/needed instead of printf.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Boost.Format is kind of a "type-safe printf".